# argocd login redirect loop for SSO

Tags: argocd

I'm using argocd with JumpCloud for SSO. For some reason, it periodically gets into a weird state where clicking on the login button redirects back to the login page, a not found error, or an infinite redirect loop. It's intermittent and can sometimes (but not always) be fixed by deleting cookies, clearing cache, and/or restarting or deleting the argocd-server pods.

`charts/argocd/values.yaml`

```yaml
environment: ""
argo-cd:
  redis-ha:
    enabled: true

  controller:
    replicas: 1
    metrics:
      enabled: true
      serviceMonitor:
        enabled: true
        namespace: kube-system
        additionalLabels:
          release: kube-prometheus-stack
    nodeSelector:
      eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType: ON_DEMAND
    args:
      appResyncPeriod: 20
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 1000m
        memory: 768Mi

  server:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
      serviceMonitor:
        enabled: true
        namespace: kube-system
        additionalLabels:
          release: kube-prometheus-stack
    nodeSelector:
      eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType: ON_DEMAND
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 50m
        memory: 128Mi
    rbacConfigCreate: false
    config:
      dex.config: |
        connectors:
          - type: ldap
            name: jumpcloud.com
            id: ad
            config:
              # Ldap server address
              host: ldap.jumpcloud.com:636
              insecureNoSSL: false
              insecureSkipVerify: true
              # Variable name stores ldap bindDN in argocd-secret
              bindDN: "uid=dexservice,ou=Users,o=myorganizationid,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
              # Variable name stores ldap bind password in argocd-secret
              bindPW: "mysecurepassword"
              usernamePrompt: Jumpcloud Username
              userSearch:
                baseDN: ou=Users,o=myorganizationid,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com
                username: uid
                idAttr: entryDN
                emailAttr: mail
                nameAttr: cn
              groupSearch:
                baseDN: ou=Users,o=myorganizationid,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com
                filter: "(|(cn=K8S-Admin)(cn=K8S-ReadOnly))"
                userMatchers:
                - userAttr: entryDN
                  groupAttr: member
                nameAttr: cn
      repositories: |
        - url: git@github.com:myorgname/myreponame
          sshPrivateKeySecret:
            name: ssh-private-key-secret
            key: id_ed25519
    service:
      type: NodePort

  dex:
    nodeSelector:
      eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType: ON_DEMAND

  redis:
    nodeSelector:
      eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType: ON_DEMAND

  repoServer:
    replicas: 2
    nodeSelector:
      eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType: ON_DEMAND

  applicationSet:
    replicaCount: 2

  configs:
    params:
      server.insecure: true
```

`charts/argocd/templates/argocd-rbac-cm.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-rbac-cm
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: {{ (index .Chart.Dependencies 0).Version }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: argocd
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-rbac-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: argocd
data:
  policy.default: role:none
  scopes: '[groups, email]'
  policy.csv: |
    p, role:none, *, *, */*, deny
    g, K8S-Admin, role:admin
    g, K8S-ReadOnly, "role:admin"
```

`charts/argocd/templates/ingress.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  annotations:
    "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: {{ .Values.environment }}
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme": "internal"
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type": "instance"
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports": '[{"HTTP":80},{"HTTPS":443}]'
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol": HTTP
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path": "/"
    "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect": '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    "external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname": argocd.{{ .Values.hostName }}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: argocd.{{ .Values.hostName }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ssl-redirect
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: argocd-server
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

We're currently experiencing similar (weird) issues with our Argo CD stack that utilizes DEX as an LDAP connector. DEX logs shows successful authentication, yet when returning to Argo CD, it intermittently seems to switch back to an OICD based login method and denies access with varying error messages completely unrelated to LDAP.

Recent communication on this topic on Argo's Slack Channel showed that this is not a known issue, but might have to do with running Argo in HA mode, i.e. using two or more `argocd-server`-instances, which was exactly our setup.

I've scaled down `argocd-server` to one instance only for the time being. Until now, the issue hasn't resurfaced.

This might not be an exact answer, but rather (hopefully) provide a helpful hint as to where to look for a possible solution. Approval pending. :)

Comment: This solved it for me as well. Opened an issue with them:
https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/15079